# Get substrings from an array rows, Regex?

Tags: php, arrays, regex

Got an array with this kind of data in every row:

> 2015/2016-0 5 Gruuu 105 Fac Cience Comm 10073 Com Aud **103032** Tech Real TV 4 First Time feb First Quad 6.0 1 **Lory Johnson, Nicholas** **1334968** 47107453A Cory Stein, Hellen Monster Cr. pie 5 a 3-2 08704 Iguan NewYork HelenMonste.Caldu@ecamp.ex.net eileen@hot.ex.net 617788050 Si 105 / 968 17/07/2015 0

Is it possible to get and kept only **highlighted** values?

I thought something like "get the 6 numbers that always go together", "get the 7 numbers that always go together" and "get the two strings before the comma and the string after the comma and before the 7 numbers that always go together"

This is the way I'm filling the array from a file, so the array with this kind of rows is called `$csvrow`:

```
if ($type == 'text/csv'){
    $csvData = file_get_contents($tname);
    $csvrows = explode(PHP_EOL, $csvData);
    $csvarray = array();

    foreach ($csvrows as $csvrow){
    if (strpos($csvrow, '10073') !== false) {
        $csvarray[] = str_getcsv($csvrow);
        echo $csvrow."<br><br>";

    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by just `Bold values`?

Comment: Sorry @Tushar I pressed enter before finish. : \

Comment: I still don't understand what the pattern is, can you explain it

Comment: Well I thought something like "get the 6 numbers that always go together", "get the 7 numbers that always go together"  and "get the two strings before the comma and the string after the comma and before the 7 numbers that always go together". It's not easy to explain and to encode either.

Comment: Please put the new line in your initial input, I don't see the pattern here. Is there any logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$str = '2015/2016-0 5 Gruuu 105 Fac Cience Comm 10073 Com Aud 103032 Tech Real TV 4 First Time feb First Quad 6.0 1 Lory Johnson, Nicholas 1334968 47107453A Cory Stein, Hellen Monster Cr. pie 5 a 3-2 08704 Iguan NewYork HelenMonste.Caldu@ecamp.ex.net eileen@hot.ex.net 617788050 Si 105 / 968 17/07/2015 0';
```

Get 6 numbers:

```
preg_match('~\d{6}~', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Get "get the two strings before the comma and the string after the comma and before the 7 numbers that always go together":

```
preg_match('~([^\s]+\s+[^\s]+)\s*,\s*([^\s]+)\s*(\d{7})~', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

The outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 103032
)

Array
(
    [0] => Lory Johnson, Nicholas 1334968
    [1] => Lory Johnson
    [2] => Nicholas
    [3] => 1334968
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Mvorisek! That's exactly what I need :)
Just out of curiosity ... Is there a way to put the two regex expressions together in only one expression?

Comment: `preg_match('~\d{6}.*([^\s]+\s+[^\s]+)\s*,\s*([^\s]+)\s*(\d{7})~', $str, $matches);` just merge the regexes and add `.*` between - this will match the text between the two matches. If my answer answered your question, feel free to mark it as answer.

Comment: Great!! thanks a lot for your help and time :)

Answer (score 0):

Please be more precise on your actual structure. With the information given, you could come up with the following code:

```
$regex = '~
    (?<number1>\b\d{6}\b)      # match six digits surrounded by word boundaries
    \K                         # throw away anything to the left
    .*?                        # match everything lazily
    (?<name>[a-zA-Z\h,]+)      # match a letter (lower/uppercase), comma 
                               # or horizontal whitespaces
    (?=\b(?P<number2>\d{7})\b) # make sure the match is followed
                               # by seven digits with word boundaries
~x';

$str = 'your_string_here';
preg_match_all($regex, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
// e.g. number1
echo $matches["number1"][0]; // 103032
```

Your desired output is in the group `number1`, `name` and `number2` respectively.
See [a demo on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/vgBJEx).